# Could I use spiders to catch unwanted insects?

Tags: arachnology

I was wondering if its possible to catch spiders and place them in my greenhouse in order to kill unwanted insect that feast on my plants? I don't really mind presence of spiders since then are not dangerous in my country (Czech republic).

Common species that live outside are Araneus diadematus, we got many that live in presence of human like Tegenaria domestica, but I read that they are type that live at human build constructions and can't really survive outside.

Comment: Spiders can definitely be used for pest control along with some beneficial insects, such as ladybugs. Some care should be taken in case the introduced spiders actually cause more harm by, for example, killing [ladybugs](http://www.offthegridnews.com/food/ladybugs-pest-or-powerful-pest-control/). An alternative approach is to grow plants that attract beneficial spiders and insects:  
https://dengarden.com/gardening/Useful-Insects-For-Plants  

https://www.organiclesson.com/beneficial-insects-garden-pest-control/  

Perhaps you'll get more info over at gardening.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called [biological pest control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_pest_control). Lacewings and earwigs are more common, but there are ways to use spiders.

http://unossc1.undp.org/GSSDAcademy/SIE/Docs/Vol4/Rearing_spiders.pdf

http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.en.29.010184.001503?journalCode=ento